# Get all Perforce local workspace root directories using p4 command

Tags: command-line, perforce, workspace

I want to get a list of all local workspaces available on my machine using the p4 command.

I know about this command that returns the latest workspace client root:

```
p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info
```

And this command:

```
p4 workspaces -u <myusername>
```

that lists my users' workspaces, but I need to extract just the root directory paths. I would like to do that with just the p4 command if possible, without writing any shell scripts. I tried using `-e` with some SQL-style query but it didn't really work. I'm running Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you´re looking for, if I understand your question fully.

```
p4 clients --me
```

This should give you the P4CLIENT and the absolute path to the root directory, for each workspace you have.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that's it! I just extract the paths from the output using some regular expressions. Thank you!

Comment: Do `p4 -F %domainMount% clients --me` to get just the client roots.